# Is it safe to use static Encoding objects from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

MSDN page on the [`Encoding` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) says instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe. Does this mean we are not supposed to use `Encoding.UTF8` and similar static `Encoding` objects from anywhere except the main thread?

This would mean we should construct new `UTF8Encoding` objects when needed in a multithreaded environment. I would call that a surprising design decision, considering that `Encoding` objects shouldn't need state.

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8` is not an instance member - isn't this fine?

Comment: @Scott `Encoding.UTF8` is static, but the object it returns is an `Encoding` object with instance members you call to do actual encoding/decoding.

Comment: "Encoding objects shouldn't need state" is an incorrect assumption. Say you are decoding a stream of multibyte characters... Are you part-way through a previous character on this read of the stream?

Comment: @spender This is what `Encoder` and `Decoder` classes were made for. You get those by calling `Encoding.GetEncoder()` and `Encoding.GetDecoder()`.

Comment: Utf8Encoder and Utf8Decoder have internal HasState and Reset() members.  Necessary to keep track of surrogates.  Utf8Encoding also keeps state to track whether the BOM was emitted and whether it should throw an exception or emit the diamond.  So no, not safe.  And *very* hard to debug, this only goes wrong once a year.

Comment: @HansPassant Why does `UTF8Encoding` track whether it emitted BOM? `Encoding` is only supposed to be directly used for 'clean-slate' conversions between complete arrays of data. At least according to the MSDN page I linked to, it's not supposed to be used for data divided into blocks. Doing what it was meant to do shouldn't require state. Knowing whether to throw an exception etc. doesn't apply to `Encoding` objects returned by the static properties, since those are read-only.

Comment: Sigh, what the heck is the point of latching onto such a minor detail?  Fine, use it anyway for all I care, this goes wrong so infrequently that your user has no good way to figure out that it is bug in your program.

Comment: @Hans: _"Utf8Encoding also keeps state to track whether the BOM was emitted"_ -- I don't believe this is true. The difference between encodings with BOM and without (technically, "preamble") is what is returned when the `GetPreamble()` method is called. It's up to whatever code is actually _using_ the `Encoding` object (e.g. a `StreamWriter`) to remember whether the BOM has been emitted or not. The `Encoding` class itself never actually does.